# Creating evenly spaced time intervals while interpolating values from original data

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a csv file that is formatted like this:

```
Time      |  RH
----------------
1491062400| 39.0
1491062590| 40.0
1491062891| 40.0
1491063191| 39.0
1491063490| 40.0
1491063791| 40.0
1491064090| 39.0
1491064390| 38.0
1491064689| 39.0
1491064990| 40.0
1491065289| 39.0
1491065590| 39.0
1491065890| 40.0
1491022991| 39.0
1491023292| 39.0
1491023592| 38.0
1491023893| 39.0
1491024194| 39.0
1491024494| 39.0
1491024795| 40.0
1491025094| 40.0
1491025395| 39.0
1491025695| 40.0
1491025995| 40.0
1491026295| 39.0
1491026594| 39.0
1491026895| 37.0
1491027195| 39.0
1491027494| 39.0
```

But the time intervals, as seen, jumps randomly (i.e a 3 minute jump, 10 minute jump, etc.) I need to figure out a way to evenly space this time data into 5 minute intervals while interpolating the value under 'RH' to keep everything accurate.

Comment: What have you tried? We tend to prefer if people have done some effort first!

Comment: I am not entirely sure what to do. I am new to python and not very skilled at computer programming. however i did try using interp1d(table_clean['Time'].values.flatten(), table_clean['RH'].values.flatten(), kind='cubic')  with no success as my value is staying in the nd dimension instead of the 1d dimension